# AutoCompleteTextView crops the last row

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a AutoCompleteTextView, the list for which is loaded from a custom ArrayAdapter.

In the view, I have 2 lines one name and second is email id.

My problem is that when I have a single item in the list, it crops the item. (Please see the attached image)
[image]

Any Idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Update: looks like a fading issue, can some one help me in removing the fading for this?

Comment: try giving more height to the textview which you have defined to dropdown(a layout I suppose). or use wrap_content.

Comment: @sat, I am using Wrap_content right now.. If I give extra height, the view looks very odd when I have more elements.

Comment: Have you tried android:minHeight option ? It may help for single  item.

Comment: @sat, any idea how to remove the Cache Color hint?

Comment: For what purpose you want to change cacheColor hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sat suggested, min Height did the trick for me.

It looks better, but vertical scroll still appears.